# JavaScript Show loading gif while Iframe loads

Tags: javascript, iframe, loading

I need a loading GIF to show up while the iframe is loading.
This is what I came up with:

```
<div id="m-load" style="position:relative;top:45%;left:45%;">
<img src="images/loader.gif"/></div>
<iframe src="http://myserver.com/myfile.html" id="m-iframe"></iframe>
```

And in the iframe source file I entered:(myfile.html)

```
<head>
<script>
top.document.getElementById('m-load').style.display ="none";
</script>
</head>
```

But this won't work in Firefox (permission denied).
Any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do it on the **same** page using `onload` event which fires after all iframes are loaded like this:

```
// show loading image

window.onload = function(){
  // hide loading image
}
```

---

```
<img id="img" src="images/loader.gif"/></div>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('img').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`iframes` are not allowed to just access parent content willy-nilly. Suppose a hacker finds a vulnerability in your page (say, you have a comment form that allows `iframe`s for whatever purpose. If they can just access the parent, they get to walk all over your site.

You could use instead `postMessage`. Because both the page and the iframe now agree on how to communicate, and what constitutes valid communication, you don't have arbitrary access to your page. There's a good tutorial at http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/18/postmessage-in-html5-to-send-messages-between-windows-and-iframes/